# Android Emulator can not connect to SailsJs server via Socket.IO

Tags: android, socket.io, sails.js

I am developing an Android app. I would like it to communicate with a SailsJS server via SocketIO. I am using socket.io for Android(com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client) as the socket.io library in the android app.

I run it on an emulator while doing the development. The initialization code is as below:

```
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket(Config.SERVER_URL);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Config.SERVER_URL is set to be "http://10.0.2.2:1337".

It always reports "connect_error". What should I do to get it connected?

Comment: Paste the stackTrace here maybe?

Comment: You happen to write mSocket.connect(); somewhere in your code?

Comment: And by the way your server IP is kind of weird. Is it correct IP?